# Shift register clocking and latching delay from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, multiplexer, shift-register

When latching or clocking a shift register from a microcontroller, should there be a delay in between setting the clock or latch pin to high and then resetting it to low? How long is this delay typically? For example if I set the data pin, and then set the clock to high and then immediately back to low in the next line of code, would that be sufficient to clock in the data?

Comment: Yes, but how long depends on the exact part number of the shift register; if you post an example datasheet we can point out which value it is.

Comment: @pjc50 I'm using these two types of shift registers:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf
The former is used to source, the latter is used to sink. They are being controlled by a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no typical delays, just the datasheet...

A quick glance through the two datasheets learns that at 5V none of the required delays is more than 100 ns, so you could use that and be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's possible to make a delay at the nanoscale for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: On second thought, there is a nanosleep() function in time.h that might be useful.

Comment: You did not mention the Pi in your original question (you mention a microcontroller, which the Pi isn't). BTW you can do ns level sleeps on a Pi if you program it bare-metal (without the OS).

Comment: Would nanosleep not work well with Raspberry Pi? I would prefer to keep the OS because I need to do some high-level tasks such as web scraping as well.